# Non abelian exterior square of a group.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, combinations

The non-abelian exterior square $G\wedge G$ of a group $G$ is defined as a group generated by the words $g\wedge h$, $g,h \in G$ related to the conditions

1. $g\wedge g=1$
2. $(g\wedge h)(h\wedge g)=1$
3. $g\wedge g'h=(g\wedge g').(^{g'}g\wedge ^{g'}h)$
4. $gg'\wedge h=(^gg'\wedge ^gh).(g\wedge h)$

where $^gh=ghg^{-1}$. The non abelian tensor square $G \otimes G$ of a group $G$ is determined by many authors [For the groups of order $p^2q$ it is computed](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/259646695_On_the_nonabelian_tensor_square_and_capability_of_groups_of_order_p2q). KIndly give me some idea or refrence, so I can compute it for some groups.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard notation for the nonabelian exterior square is $G\wedge G$ (just like the notation for the nonabelian tensor square is $G\otimes G$). The notation $G*G$ is commonly understood to represent the free product of $G$ with itself, and I strongly encourage you to drop it and adopt the standard one.

Some references:

1. Blyth, R. D.; Fumagalli, F.; Morigi, M.
   **A survey of recent progress on non-abelian tensor squares of groups.** *Ischia group theory 2010*, 26–38, World Sci. Publ., Hackensack, NJ, 2012. MR3184981
2. Russell D. Blyth and Robert Fitzgerald Morse. **Computing the nonabelian tensor squares of polycyclic groups.** *J. Algebra* 321 (2009), no. 8, 2139–2148. MR 2501513
3. Blyth, Russell D.; Fumagalli, Francesco; Morigi, Marta.
   **Some structural results on the non-abelian tensor square of groups.** 
   *J. Group Theory* 13 (2010), no. 1, 83–94. MR2604847
4. R. Brown, D. L. Johnson, and E. F. Robertson, **Some computations of nonabelian tensor products of groups**, *J. Algebra* 111 (1987), no. 1, 177–202. MR0913203

See also [this previous answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/43055/a-question-about-non-abelian-tensor-product/43068#43068).

Comment: I have studied some of these research articles, but all of them are related to non abelian tensor square of a group.

Comment: @MANISHANKARPANDEY And the nonabelian exterior square is a quotient modulo a well-defined subgroup. You can calculate the quotient if you know the group. And the large commutative diagram in the Blyth, Fumagalli and Morigi paper, which I reproduced in the linked answer, gives you *two* different ways to fit the nonabelian exterior square into an exact sequence with either the nonabelian tensor square, or the Schur multiplier and the commutator subgroup. So they do give you ways of making the computation.