# Non abelian exterior square of $Sym(4)\wedge Sym(4)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, group-presentation

The non abelian exterior square of a group is defined  [Non abelian exterior square of a group.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3279493/non-abelian-exterior-square-of-a-group). I want to compute it for Sym$(4)$. It is well known that the following sequence of groups is exact:
$$1\rightarrow M(Sym(4))\rightarrow Sym(4)\wedge Sym(4) \rightarrow A_4\rightarrow 1$$
where $M(Sym(4))$ is the Schur multiplier of $Sym(4)$. From here I can guess that the order of $Sym(4)\wedge Sym(4)=24$, but not more than that. Is there any way to compute it. My question is that $\textbf{is this short exact sequence splits?}$

We have many presentations for $Sym(4)$:

$Sym(4)=\langle x_1,x_2,x_3| x_1^2=x_2^3=x_3^4=1=x_1x_2x_3\rangle=\langle x_1,x_2,x_3| x_1^2=x_2^2=x_3^2=1=(x_1x_2)^2=(x_2x_3)^3=(x_3x_1)^4\rangle $. Can we use any presentation to compute this.